# Widget won't move

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

```
class BukaCatatan(Page):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        super().__init__(master, **kw)

        self.create_frame_content().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

    def create_frame_content(self):
        self.frame_content = ttk.Frame(self)

        label_title = ttk.Label(self.frame_content, text='BUKA CATATAN', font=('Tektn', 18))
        label_title.grid(row=0,column=1)

        return self.frame_content
```

Why is it that `label_title` (widget label) won't move even when I change the row and the column?

Comment: Empty rows and empty columns have a size of zero. If you have nothing in column 0, then column 1 will be at the far left edge.

Comment: Where do you want to move the widget to? Are you trying to move the widget to the left/right of another widget?

Comment: i want to move the widget to the north center position